# Multi-document transactions cannot be run in a sharded collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, mongoose, mongodb-query

Iam trying to do update two document in two different collection as a transaction. But whenever i run the transaction as suggested in the documentation mentioned below, i get the error

```
Multi-document transactions cannot be run in a sharded collection in mongoDB
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/use-multi-document-transactions.

Is there any mongodb version support multi-document support on shared collection rather than fixed collection ?

Comment: Could you verify the doc once, It is said like "Multi-document transactions are supported within an **`unsharded`** collection in API version 4.0. Multi-document transactions are **not supported** across collections or in **sharded collections** in 4.0."

Comment: What mongo server version?

Comment: @dododo The version is 4.2

Comment: @Balaji I'm asking is there any version supports in sharded collection. I can see its supporting in version 4.2, when i checked in chatGPT . But not able to find any reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Multi-document transactions cannot be run in a sharded collection in mongoDB

As mentioned in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/use-multi-document-transactions), the multi-document transactions are supported within an non-sharded collection in API version 4.0. This is the reason for the occurrence of the error. In this Mongo DB API version 4.2 [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-42), it is clearly mentioned as the **Multi-document transactions are supported only within a single non-sharded collection.** So, it doesn't support multi-document transactions with sharded key in Mongo DB API version 4.2.

Below is the code that supports multi-document transactions with single non-sharded key collection in Mongo DB API version 4.2.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const uri = "mongodb://<username>:<password>@<username>.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retryWrites=false";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function main() {
    try {
        await client.connect();

        const db = client.db("users");

        await db.collection('friends').insertOne({ name: "Tom" });
        await db.collection('friends').insertOne({ name: "Mike" });

        const session = client.startSession();
        session.startTransaction();

        try {
            await db.collection('friends').updateOne({ name: "Tom" }, { $set: { friendOf: "Mike" } });
            
            await db.collection('friends').updateOne({ name: "Mike" }, { $set: { friendOf: "Tom" } });

            await session.commitTransaction();
        } catch (error) {
            await session.abortTransaction();
            throw error; 
        } finally {
            session.endSession();
        }
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

**Output:**

[image]